# Separating texts from a File with String.Split nothing happens

Tags: java, regex, string, text, split

EDITED

Im trying to split a text into an Array. I have a .txt made by different text, like a collection of texts. I need the whole text of each different text in the .txt in a position of the Array. 
Im recovering the text from the file with a JFileChooser. And then im trying to process it with "regex" String.Split and then trying to print it. "The first part of the FileChooser it works, but when trying to separate the text in the Array i dont know if its working, because the System.out does not print the expected Array whit all the texts."

This is an example of the .txt each text is separated by a "*TEXT".

```
*TEXT 017 01/04/63 PAGE 020
THE ALLIES AFTER NASSAU IN DECEMBER 1960, THE U.S ........
*TEXT 020 01/04/63 PAGE 021
THE ROAD TO JAIL IS PAVED WITH NONOBJECTIVE ART SINCE THE KREMLIN'S SHARPEST BARBS THESE DAYS ARE AIMED AT MODERN ART AND WESTERN ESPIONAGE...
*TEXT 025 01/04/63 PAGE 024
RED CHINA FIXING FRONTIERS RED CHINA PRODUCED A SECOND SURPRISE LAST WEEK...
```

An this is my code, first the FileChooser and then the String.Split

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Reader{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        File inFile;
        FileReader fr;
        BufferedReader bufReader;
        JFileChooser chooser;

        int reply;
        String doc = "";

        String line;
        try{

            chooser = new JFileChooser();
            reply = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            doc = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().getPath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            inFile = new File(doc);
            fr = new FileReader(inFile);
            bufReader = new BufferedReader (fr);

            do{
                line = bufReader.readLine();
                if(line ==null )
                    return;
            } while(line!=null);

            //**HERE STARTS THE STRING.SPLIT**
            //"line" at the end of next line it supposed to be the whole .txt
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(line)));
            StringBuilder br = new StringBuilder();
            String newLine ="";
            while(true){
                if(line == null)
                    break;
                br.append(line);
            }
            newLine = br.toString();
            String arr[] = newLine.split("\\*TEXT");
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
            //**HERE ENDS**


            bufReader.close();

        }//end try
        catch(Exception e)
        {   System.out.println("error: "+e.getMessage());   }

    }//main
}//end class reader
```

Thanks for your help! :3

Comment: Check your `while(true)` loop. In fact your `do-while` loop isn't doing anything either.

Comment: "*But it doesn't work.*" That is not correct problem description. You need to be more specific so (1) we could help you better/faster (2) future readers with similar problems could find your question and possibly answer to their problem.

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: "The first part of the FileChooser it works, but when trying to separate the text in the Array i dont know if its working, because the System.out does not print the expected Array whit all the texts."

Comment: Don't add relevant informations only in comments (not everyone reads comments). Use [edit] option placed below your post to edit it, so you can include your problem description there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, your code never reaches the call to `split`. Your code has only two paths: the user cancels the file chooser dialog, which causes a `NullPointerException`, or a file is chosen, which inevitably hits the return statement in

```
...
do{
            line = bufReader.readLine();
            if(line ==null )
                return;
   } while(line!=null);
```

Second, the line

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(line)));
```

tries to **open the file** with name specified by the value of variable `line` which is probably not what you want.

A fixed version of your code would be:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Reader{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        File inFile;
        FileReader fr;
        BufferedReader bufReader;
        JFileChooser chooser;

        int reply;

        try{

            chooser = new JFileChooser();
            reply = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            // Read all the lines in the file at once
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            // Merge the read lines into a String
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line : lines){
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append('\n');
            }

            String newLine = sb.toString();

            // Split the String
            String arr[] = newLine.split("\\*TEXT");
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));

        }//end try
        catch(Exception e)
        {   System.out.println("error: "+e.getMessage());   }

    }//main
}//end class reader
```

Note the API classes `Files` and `Paths` are available starting Java API 1.7 only.

Comment: It gives me an error on this line:
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Multiple markers at this line: 
Paths cannot be solved, 
Files cannot be solved, 
StandardCharsets cannot be resolved to a variable
@Sergio Feo

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually ReadAllLines is only available from Java 7 on. The answer will be edited to reflect this limitation

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text using this regex:

```
^(?=\*TEXT)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/rV6bW1/1)**